# How to make Perl's XML::Libxml serializer to use utf-8 encoding?

Tags: xml, perl, serialization, utf-8

I'd like to serialize an xml with XML::LibXML, but it always converts utf-8 characters to html representations: I get &#xE1; from "á", etc...
How can I make it use utf-8 instead?

```
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;
use utf8;

my $str = '<item><name>árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép</name></item>';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $str);

print $str."\n";
print $dom->serialize(1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><item><name>árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép</name></item>';
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $str );
print $doc->serialize(1);
```

or

```
my $str = '<item><name>árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép</name></item>';
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $str );
$doc->setEncoding("UTF-8");    
print $doc->serialize(1);
```